# Django loop all existing record to save but only one record save

Tags: django

this is my code in html

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2 style="font-weight: bold;">Required Documents:</h2>
    </td>
</tr>
{% for d in doc %}
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input type="file" name="myfile-{{d.id}}" value="{{d.id}}" style="outline: none;" required/>
        {{d.id}}{{d.Description}}
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```py
def enrollmentform(request):
    id = request.GET.get('StudentID')
    students = StudentProfile.objects.all().filter(id=id)
    doc = DocumentRequirement.objects.all().filter()
    return render(request, 'accounts/EnrollmentForm.html',
                  {"doc": doc})
```

this is my logic on how to save my record

```py
myfile = request.FILES['myfile-6']
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
    Student_Users=studentname, Payment_Type=payment,
    Education_Levels=educationlevel, School_Year=schoolyear
)
insert_doc = StudentsSubmittedDocument(
    Students_Enrollment_Records =  V_insert_data,
    Document = myfile
)
insert_doc.save()
```

I don't have idea on how to loop this **myfile = request.FILES['myfile-6']**
with the existing id of Table Documents. please help me guys, im stuck on this problem 3days

for example if the student comply the 4 required documents it will save like this

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATrPu.png)

in my case it save only 1 record,

[wrong saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fij0m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have many inputs with the same name, this can be repeated

```
<input type="file" name="myfile">
```

In your view this list of submitted files can be accessed by using `getlist`

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('myfile')
```

Then you loop over the files in your view

```
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
    Student_Users=studentname,
    Payment_Type=payment,
    Education_Levels=educationlevel,
    School_Year=schoolyear
)
for file in request.FILES.getlist('myfile'):
    StudentsSubmittedDocument.objects.create(
        Students_Enrollment_Records=V_insert_data,
        Document=file
    )
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question sir, i got  this error from your answer 'insert_doc' is not defined